# Org-Mode table to s-expressions

Tags: emacs, org-mode, s-expression

I would like to export from Org-Mode tables to s-expressions.

```
| first  | second | thrid  |
|--------+--------+--------|
| value1 | value2 | value3 |
| value4 | value5 | value6 |
```

Would turn into:

```
((:FIRST "value1" :SECOND "value2" :THIRD "value3")
 (:FIRST "value4" :SECOND "value5" :THIRD "value6"))
```

I plan on writing such a setup if it doesn't exist yet but figured I'd tap into the stackoverflow before I start reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does the trick.  It has minimal error checking.

The interface to use is either the programmatic interface:

```
(org-table-to-sexp <location-of-beginning-of-table> <location-of-end-of-table>)
```

In which case it'll return the sexp you requested.

If you wanted an interactive usage, you can call the following command to operate on the table in the [region](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Using-Region.html#Using-Region).  So, set the mark at the beginning of the table, move to the end, and type:

```
M-x insert-org-table-to-sexp
```

That will insert the desired sexp immediately after the table in the current buffer.

Here is the code:

```
(defun org-table-to-sexp-parse-line ()
  "Helper, returns the current line as a list of strings"
  (save-excursion
    (save-match-data
      (let ((result nil)
            (end-of-line (save-excursion (end-of-line) (point))))
        (beginning-of-line)
        (while (re-search-forward "\\([^|]*\\)|" end-of-line t)
          (let ((match (mapconcat 'identity (split-string (match-string-no-properties 1)) " ")))
            (if (< 0 (length match))
                ;; really want to strip spaces from front and back
                (push match result))))
        (reverse result)))))

(require 'cl)
(defun org-table-to-sexp (b e)
  "Parse an org-mode table to sexp"
  (save-excursion
    (save-match-data
      (goto-char b)
      (let ((headers (mapcar
                      (lambda (str)
                        (make-symbol (concat ":" (upcase str))))
                      (org-table-to-sexp-parse-line)))
            (sexp nil))
        (forward-line 1)                ;skip |--+--+--| line
        (while (< (point) e)
          (forward-line 1)
          (let ((line-result nil))
            (mapcar* (lambda (h e)
                       (push h line-result)
                       (push e line-result))
                     headers
                     (org-table-to-sexp-parse-line))
            (if line-result
                (push (reverse line-result)
                      sexp))))
        sexp))))

(defun insert-org-table-to-sexp (b e)
  "Convert the table specified by the region and insert the sexp after the table"
  (interactive "r")
  (goto-char (max b e))
  (print (org-table-to-sexp b e) (current-buffer)))
```

Comment: I am not sure how I would use that function. I added it to my .emacs eval'd it but I don't get how I'd use it.

If you could expand on how to use that, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @Chris I added an interactive command which you can just type.  I think the larger question is: how do you want to use it?